# SimpleModal opened from iframe to parent body does not close with "simplemodal-close" class

Tags: javascript, simplemodal, eric-martin-modal

I'm using SimpleModal 1.4.4 (by Eric Martin) because it has an easy way of opening a modal from an iframe to the parent. I really like that, thanks to the developer!

My question is:

Now that I have it working the way I want to, I cannot close it with class="simplemodal-close". Here's the code:

```
$(window.parent.document).find('#basic-modal-content').modal({
    opacity: 30,
    closeHTML: "<a href='#'>close</a>",
    overlayClose: true,
    minWidth: picW,
    minHeight: picH,
    position: [30,xPosition],
    appendTo: $(window.parent.document).find('body'),
});
```

Clicking on the overlay works perfectly but clicking on the 'close' link doesn't!

What am I missing?

I'm creating the modal div and an image placeholder dinamically each time an image on the iframe is clicked (basically, an image is clicked and the modal opens up with it). This is how:

```
//Create Div and Image Placeholder
var modalDiv = $("<div/>").appendTo($(window.parent.document).find('body'));
modalDiv.attr("id", "basic-modal-content");
var imgPlace = $("<div/>").appendTo($(window.parent.document).find('#basic-modal-content'));
imgPlace.attr("id", "image-place");

modalDiv.css("width", "100%");
imgPlace.css("width", "100%");
imgPlace.css("margin", "0 auto");
imgPlace.css("text-align", "center");
```

Comment: Can you paste in the html for your SimpleModal?

Comment: might be a z-index issue. Need to see  HTML and CSS.

Comment: Its better add a [CodeSnippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or JSFiddle to your question

Comment: I just edited the code with the html and css. Of course I'm also using the css that comes with SimpleModal.